# Data format error in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to access excel data from a file using windows form to input latitude and longitude information. However, When I debug it, it throws "input string not in correct format" error. I am using the following code:

```
namespace Excel_Access
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        string myDouble2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            string cellValue = "";
            string cellValue1 = "";
            string cellValue2 = "";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =G:\Manish Dixit\TAMU\BS2015\SolarInsolation\Excel Sheets\Clr_Index.xlsm; Extended Properties= Excel 12.0");
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select*from[Sheet2$]", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
            da.Fill(dt);
            int i = 1;
            do
            {
            cellValue = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();

                if(double.Parse(cellValue)==double.Parse(textBox1.Text))
                    cellValue1 = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                    if (double.Parse(cellValue1) == double.Parse(textBox2.Text))
                    {
                        cellValue2 = dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(cellValue2);
                    }

                    i++;

            }

            while (i < 441);


            //myDouble2 = ExcelDB(10, "L2");
            //MessageBox.Show("The value is " +myDouble2);
        }


    }
}
```

Could you please suggest why this is happening? The input values of latitude and longitude are in decimal.Please see the attached image of the data I am trying to access. [See data image in Excel file here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg7ab.jpg)

Comment: What line gives the error? We basically have to guess right now what throws the error.

Comment: Is `cellValue` ever null? Did you try setting a breakpoint and seeing what the values are at the line it throws the error? I bet you'll figure it out if you do...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses! The error is in the second IF statement: if (double.Parse(cellValue1) == double.Parse(textBox2.Text))

Answer (score 1):

You have no error handling on your double.parse.  I would look at the values you are trying to double.parse in your debugger and add some error handling or use double.TryParse.  see [Input string was not in correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321514/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

```
double.Parse(textBox2.Text)
```

If this is not a valid double an exception 'Input string was not in a correct format' will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks Kmcnamee and all other who responded! I found that there was something wrong with the IF statement that was causing a null value to exist. I finally caught it using the debugger and resolved it. Thanks a lot once again!