# Int.TryParse() returns false always

Tags: c#, tryparse, int32

I have following code

```
 int varOut;
 int.TryParse(txt1.Text, out varOut); // Here txt1.Text = 4286656181793660
```

Here txt1.Text is the random 16 digit number generated by JavaScript which is an integer. But the above code always return false i.e. varOut value is always zero.

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: So you've read the MSDN [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which says "false ...  represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue". Could you please clarify what part of that statement you need help with?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The limit for `int` (`32-bit` integer) is `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`. Your number is too large.

For large `integer` number such as your case, try to `Parse` using `long.TryParse` (or `Int64.TryParse` since `Int64` is `long` in C#) instead. The limit for `long` number is of the range of `-9.2e18 to 9.2e18`*

```
long varOut;
long.TryParse(txt1.Text, out varOut); // Here txt1.Text = 4286656181793660
```

It should be sufficient for your number, which is only around `4.2e15` (`4,286,656,181,793,660`).

Alternatively, you may want to consider using `decimal.TryParse` if you want to have [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) number (containing fraction, higher precision).

```
decimal varOut;
decimal.TryParse(txt1.Text, out varOut); // Here txt1.Text = 4286656181793660
```

It is `128-bit` data type, with the range of `-7.9e28 to 7.9e28`, and `28-29` significant digits precision, fits best for any calculation involving money.

And, as a last remark to complete the answer, it may be **unsafe** to use `double` - do *not* use it. Although `double` has a very high range of `±5.0 × 10e−324 to ±1.7 × 10e308`, its precision is only about 15-16 digits ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/678hzkk9.aspx)).

```
double varOut;
double.TryParse(txt1.Text, out varOut); // Not a good idea... since the input number is 16-digit Here txt1.Text = 4286656181793660
```

In this case, your number consists of 16 digits, which is in the borderline of the `double` precision. Thus, in some cases, you may end up with wrong result. Only if you are sure that your number will be *at most* 15-digit precision that you are safe to use it.

*`-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

Comment: Basically I need Int32 values only as further I am using it in a function which accepts 32-bit integer values only. Maybe I need to generate random number not greater than  2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 3):

`int` is just shorthand for `int32`; it's a 32 bit (signed) integer, meaning that it can't hold a number larger than around 2 billion.  Your number is larger than that, and so is not a valid `int` value.

Answer (score 3):

Use `MaxLength` property to limit the number of digits and user cannot enter more than `int32`.

```
TextBox.MaxLength=9
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be using value(s) which exceed the capacity of the type you're using... look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Store it as a long instead of an int.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should use `long` instead of `int`. Your number is too large for `int`

Answer (score 1):

Use long.TryParse()

Your number is too large to convert into int.

or you can use int64.tryparse