# Input string was not in a correct format. c# (New)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino

I'm having "Input string was not in a correct format." error from this code

```
rainTb.Text = " " + int.Parse(parsed[0]) * 100 / 1023;
```

There's no error in my code. Except for the error above. I've made a calculation to extract the analogue value (above calculation) from Arduino hardware via serial communication (cable). Arduino works fine though. Everything was fine though until this error shows up... Why? *cries*

p/s : I've gone through many solutions but still.. So here I am now. Sorry for my English

```
private void ProcessCOMRx(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(COMRx))
        {
            systemTb.Text = "Processing Data...";
            systemTb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
            string [] parsed = COMRx.Split(',');
            int curveNo;

            if (parsed.Count() > zedAll.GraphPane.CurveList.Count())
               curveNo = zedAll.GraphPane.CurveList.Count();                
            else                
                curveNo = parsed.Count();                

            for (int k = 0; k < curveNo; k++)
            {
                for (int j = zedAll.GraphPane.CurveList[k].NPts - 1; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    zedAll.GraphPane.CurveList[k].Points[j].Y = zedAll.GraphPane.CurveList[k].Points[j - 1].Y;
                }
                double temp = 0;                    
                try
                {
                    temp = double.Parse(parsed[k]);
                }                    
                catch                    
                {
                    systemTb.Text = "Parse Error";
                    systemTb.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                rainTb.Text = "" + int.Parse(parsed[0]) * 100 / 1023;
                phTb.Text = "" + (3.5 + int.Parse(parsed[1]) * 4.5 / 1023);
                moistTb.Text = "" + int.Parse(parsed[2]) * 100 / 1023;
                tempTb.Text = "" + int.Parse(parsed[3]) * 100 / 1023;


                zedAll.GraphPane.CurveList[k].Points[0].X = 0;
                zedAll.GraphPane.CurveList[k].Points[0].Y = temp;                  
            }

        }
        else
        {                
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(processPumpStates));
        }

    }
```

Comment: My data is via serial communication. From Arduino to Visual Studio. Arduino works fine though

Comment: What does your debugger say `parsed[ 0 ]` contains? I'm guessing it's something other than just digits with an optional leading `-`.

Comment: what is `parse[0]` contain ?

Comment: Your comment appears to be relevant to your question and should be added to the question rather than posted as a comment.

Comment: what will be the content of `parsed[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting such error on the basics of the value contained in the `parsed[0]` if it is a convertible string your code works fine else it throws the exception that you got. ie, the content inside the `parsed[0]` is not convertible to an integer, in such situations you should Use [int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead for int.Parse, it is having internal error handling, which help you to determine whether the conversion is successful or not.

So the code will looks like:

```
int tempNumber=0;
if (int.TryParse(parsed[0], out tempNumber))
{
    Textbox1.Text = " " + (tempNumber * 100 / 1023).ToString();
}
else 
{
    Textbox1.Text= "invalid zipCode";
}
```

Comment: oh so my code cannot be used that way? okay will change to this. thanks :)

Comment: sir, what if i have more than 1 parsed[0]?

Comment: I have parsed[1], parsed[2] and parsed[3]

Answer (score 1):

There are few possible cases why it happens. One is because (1) `parsed[0]` number is [too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349843/int-tryparse-returns-false-always/34349860#34349860), another is because `parsed[0]` contains (2) non-number, (3) non-recognized thousand separators, or (4) decimal separator (which should not exist in `int` parsing) in the applied culture for your code.

In all cases, please check the value of `parsed[0]` with your Visual Studio debugger and make sure that it has purely-acceptable numerical format for `int` range. Something like:

```
1234
```

Also, you may consider of

1. using `TryParse` instead of `Parse` to ensure that the non-parsed number does not cause you exception problem.
2. use `ToString()` for printing your numerical calculation result,
3. check the result of `TryParse` and
4. beware of the integer division that you potentially do in the original `int.Parse(parsed[0]) * 100 / 1023`:

Something like this:

```
 int val;
 bool result = int.TryParse(parsed[0], out val);
 if (!result)
     return; //something has gone wrong

 Textbox1.Text = " " + (val * 100d / 1023d).ToString(); //note the d
```

Comment: what if i have more than 1 parsed[0]?

Comment: I have parsed[1], parsed[2] and parsed[3]

Comment: @AqilahZainuddin you could use the same logic and use `for` loop - provided that they are all identical or almost identical in logic process. You could put that as a **new** question to further clarify if it is quite different from the current question.