# Parameter error "The input string is not formatted correctly"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In a textbox I have to write a name that is in the database, when clicking the button has to load data in the gridview, then I added the textbox.
I have the following query, I have to display the records in a gridview but I mark this error, "The input string is not formatted correctly."

I have parameters in string and an integer

```
AppData.DataSet1TableAdapters.PS_USR_ConsultaExternaTableAdapter adapter =   new AppData.DataSet1TableAdapters.PS_USR_ConsultaExternaTableAdapter();

adapter.GetData("", "", "", int.Parse(this.TextBox1.Text));
this.gvbuscar.DataSource = adapter.GetData("", "", "", int.Parse(this.TextBox1.Text));
this.gvbuscar.DataBind();
```

Comment: `int.Parse` is throwing the `FormatException` because `this.TextBox1.Text` cannot be converted to an `int`. Could happen if the text was empty or invalid like `"abc"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input string was not in a correct format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321514/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: You need to ensure that there is a check to allow only integers in the text box.