# Why this code generate exception? Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
  protected void ordersGV_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        orderdetails_lbl.Visible = true;
        int orderId=int.Parse(ordersGV.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        var query = nw.Order_Details.Where(od => od.OrderID == orderId).Select(od=>new {od.Product.ProductName,od.Quantity });
        orderdetailsGV.DataSource = query.ToList();
        orderdetailsGV.DataBind();

    }
```

I have this exception after this code:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321514/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: tl;dr the cell you are trying to read your `orderId` from doesn't contain a number.  are you *sure* that you want `Cells[1]` (the second cell in the row)?

Comment: No i want the first cell which contains select statement

Comment: Arrays are zero based, which means the first item is 0, the second item is 1, etc.

Comment: i'ts a gridView should we deal with it as an array?

Comment: well, `Cells` is an array of `Cell` objects in the `SelectedRow`, right?

Comment: if you aren't sure, put a breakpoint on the line where you are assigning your `orderId`, and inspect the value that you are getting back.  it won't be a number.

Comment: Thanks for your support dear,the issue have been solved with you recommend solution.sorry for late reply.