# Linq Input string was not in a correct format in MVC

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

The original SQL Command coded by the old programmers looks like this

```
SELECT ooe_general_id, SUM(CAST(CAST(amount AS money) AS float)) AS totalAppro, MAX(date) AS lastDate 
FROM  dbo.pmTA_OoeGeneralAppropriation
```

**Datatype: String**

```
Database Values
----------------
3,200,000.00
2916410
28,710,000.00
0.80000000000291
-1000000
```

When I try to convert the above code to Linq, an error *'Input string was not in a correct format'* shows in this line

```
totalAppro = g.Sum(p => Convert.ToDouble(p.amount))
```

I tried doing changing the code to

```
Convert.Double(string, IFormatprovider)  
Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:c}", p.amount)) 
Convert.ToDecimal(p.amount.Replace(",",""))
```

from these [Currency](http://[IFormatProvider][1]), [Convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321514/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format), [SUM LINQ](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/189653-linq-sum-with-conversion/) forums but the error still persists.

The question is what am I doing wrong here? Why did my first two codes work but this doesn't? And lastly, why is there an *'Input string was not in a correct format'* error?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
var totalAppropriationGeneralFund = (from p in db.iBudget_OoeGeneralAppropriation   
                                 where !p.amount.StartsWith("-")
                                 group p by p.ooe_general_id into g    
                                 select g).AsEnumerable().Select(g => new {
                                 id = g.Key,
                                 totalAppro = g.Sum(p => Convert.ToDecimal(p.amount.Replace(",",""))),
                                 date = g.Max(p => p.date)
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the type of amount

Comment: Can you copy your whole linq query here - what does g represent? And, may be try double.Parse() or decimal.Parse()

Comment: One of your values for `amount` is not in a valid format to be parsed by `Convert.ToDouble()`. The examples you have given thus far are fine. Check the rest of your data. It does concern me that `amount` is being cast to `money` in the original query. Why is it *not* being stored as `money`?

Comment: @TheGeneral the datatype is string

Comment: @Yatin Updated my post. Included my whole Linq Code

Comment: @DanWilson Same concern I had when I saw it. I couldn't change the datatype in the table because it is linked to another table through foreign key.

Comment: @DanWilson What is the range for the Double datatype? As for checking individually, all was fine making me wonder why an error was showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly**

Don't store or convert datatypes to string and back again. leave them as what they are, convert them for display purposes only, and definitely don't store numeric types as string in a db (just a tip).

**Secondly**

If your slightly worried about accuracy, don't use floating point values like `double` or `float`. They are notorious for losing precision and adding artefacts, use a `decimal`

**Thirdly**

- [Double.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0kb11ck8(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [NumberStyles Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **NumberStyles Enumeration** : Determines the styles permitted in numeric string arguments that are
>   passed to the Parse and TryParse methods of the integral and
>   floating-point numeric types.

The above was your problem

**Working example**

```
var list = new List<string>
   {
      "3,200,000.00",
      "2916410",
      "28,710,000.00",
      "0.80000000000291",
      "-1000000"
   };

var sum = list.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

**Output**

```
33826410.80000000000291
```

---

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uj8bYZ)

**Further reading**

[decimal (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)

**Update**

As noted in the comments by *Bagus Tesa*, you cant use `parse` methods in EF or *Linq to sql*, this has to be done in memory, i would consider changing you under laying datatype and or query

Comment: does EF supports `decimal.Parse`? on worst case you will need to do that in memory

Comment: Was having the same thoughts when I first saw the codes and datatype build in the database by the old programmers. I guess I should really change the database. Thanks for the answer and the link sr. Kudos