# pay money and changed

Tags: c#

The problem of my code is if I put value in pay money(textbox) and I turned to zero giving me an error

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

This is my code :

```
private void txtPM_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fee = lblFee.Text.Trim();
    string pm = txtPM.Text.Trim();
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(fee);
    int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(pm);

    int minus = number2 - number;
    txtChange.Text = minus.ToString().Trim();
}
```

I will put here the form

[image]

I hope you can help me thanks guys

Comment: Check whether the strings are null or empty before calling ToString(), Trim() and Convert.ToInt32() as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321514/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need `Convert.ToDecimal()` if you are working with monetary values specified as decimals. (I second the empty and null checking suggestions)

Update for clarification:

Currently, you are converting string to Int32 with the following:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(fee);
int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(pm);
```

You can instead convert to decimal with the following:

```
decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(fee);
decimal number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(pm);
```

Update2 (full method updated with null and empty checks):

```
private void txtPM_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fee = lblFee.Text.Trim();
    string pm = txtPM.Text.Trim();

    decimal number = 0;
    decimal number2 = 0;

    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fee)) number = Convert.ToDecimal(fee);
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pm)) number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(pm);

    decimal minus = number2 - number;
    txtChange.Text = minus.ToString().Trim();
}
```

Comment: how sir? the variable i use in beginning is string, cannot convert to decimal.

Comment: @FrancisDanielV.Morales and why not? What's the error? It's working for me. Also, you already use convert.toin32 so why would todecimal not work??

Comment: @FrancisDanielV.Morales I've updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: its says that 
cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to int. an explicit conversion exists

Comment: i try the updated code but if I turned the value to zero its giving me the same error sir

string fee = lblFee.Text.Trim();
            string pm = txtPM.Text.Trim();
            decimal number = Convert.ToDecimal(fee);
            decimal number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(pm);

            decimal minus = number2 - number;
            txtChange.Text = minus.ToString().Trim();

Comment: @egnomerator your answer doesn't solve the exception, the exceptions occur because `fee` and `pm` are not in the right format. The strings fee and pm must contain only digits for the conversion to be successful.

Comment: @SlavenTojić my only problem is if i put a value in paymoney (textbox) and if I erased it give me a error. can u help me?

Comment: @FrancisDanielV.Morales hopefully this last update takes care of it. I included how to check for null and empty before attempting to convert.

Comment: @FrancisDanielV.Morales I solved your problem with `int.TryParse` Take a look.

Comment: @FrancisDanielV.Morales I thinks its better to use TryParse then this approach with less code you get the same result, but it's on you to decide.

Comment: @SlavenTojić I agree that the TryParse approach and more specifically the answer by MatSnow shows a nice way to refactor the solution

Comment: @egnomerator MatSnows solution si more compact then mine but i wanted to keep it simple for the OP and dont change to much only fix the exception. And BTW MatSnows solution only works with C#7 and I don't know if the OP's complier uses C#7

Comment: @SlavenTojić Oh that's an interesting point, I didn't know it was C#7 specific. Nice point. And, I had a similar goal to yours with my suggested solution - TryParse was my initial thought, but I went with Convert.ToDecimal with the intention of staying close to the OP's approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `decimal` type because it's more appropriate for financial and monetary calculations. To avoid the exception use  `decimal.TryParse`. If the strings `pm` and `fee` are not in the right format `decimal.TryParse` will return zero and no exception will be thrown. You can also remove the `Trim()` on the last line.

```
private void txtPM_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fee = lblFee.Text.Trim();
    string pm = txtPM.Text.Trim();
    decimal number;
    decimal.TryParse(fee, out number);
    decimal number2;
    decimal.TryParse(pm, out number2);

    decimal minus = number2 - number;
    txtChange.Text = minus.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Decimal__) as already pointed out in the duplicate.
Also it makes more sense to use [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.7.1) when working with monetary values.

```
private void txtPM_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal.TryParse(lblFee.Text, out decimal number);
    decimal.TryParse(txtPM.Text, out decimal number2);

    txtChange.Text = (number2 - number).ToString();
}
```

When using C# 6.0 or earlier you have to [declare the variables in a separate statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#calling-a-method-with-an-out-argument):

```
private void txtPM_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal number;
    decimal.TryParse(lblFee.Text, out number);
    decimal number2;
    decimal.TryParse(txtPM.Text, out number2);

    txtChange.Text = (number2 - number).ToString();
}
```