# Query String in asp.net core 3.1(Input string was not in a correct format.)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
        [Route("/p/m")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add(Table t)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(HttpContext.Request.Query["Id"].ToString());
        }
```

and this my url

```
/p/m?Id=37
```

i try to get query string to my controller from url in asp.net core using this code but she give me this error

```
(Input string was not in a correct format.)
       61. int id = int.Parse(HttpContext.Request.Query["Id"].ToString());
```

Comment: The error is so descriptive, Query string is empty for the Id or it contains some extra character that is not of type int.

Comment: the query string is not empty have a value

Comment: Can you get value from the Entity classes?  The controller IActionResults should already have the values in the c# Entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not validating explicitly for numbers in the text field, in any case its better to use

```
int result=0;
if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out result))
```

Now if the result is success then you can proceed with your calculations.

[Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321514/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: return 0 but my query string value is not 0