# First C# project. I am having trouble with error handling.. and using try/catch. It would mean a lot if someone could please take a look. :)

Tags: c#, .net

https://github.com/FaisalRana/CSharp.Bakery <-- here is a link to my repo.

Recently I started a project with the following prompt: Create a bakery in c# that a user can order bread or pastries from. The program outputs the total price based on the menu.

I am learning Test Driven Development and I was able to successfully write my tests and functions and follow the red green refactor workflow.

Furthermore, I was able to handle the errors for putting in a negative number by using an if statement. I tried to do error handling for when someone types in a string instead of an integer for their order input.. but

> if (typof(input) !== integer) { } <-- this does not work in c#. The error I get when I put a non-int input in the console:

Handled exception. `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

THANK YOU

`````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Bakery.Models
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
      Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
      Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Brother Lasif's Bakery!");
      string bakeryAscii = @"
                          ....
                      .'      `.
                    .' .-'``-._ `.
                    |  / -    - ` |
                    / |'<o>  <o> | \
                  | (|    '`    |) |
                  |   \  -==-  /   |
                  |    `.____.'    |
                  \     |    |     |
                  _\_.'`-.__.-'`._/_
                .'| |`-.  /\  .-'| |`.
              _.'   \ \  `'  `'  / /   `._
            { `.    | `-.____.-' |    .' }
            /`. `./ /   __  __   \ \.' .'\
            /   `.| |   /  \/  \   | |.'   \
          (    (  \ \  \      /  / /  )    )
            `.   \  Y|   `.  .'   |Y  /   .'
              \   \ ||_ _ _\/_ _ _|| /   /
              `.  \|'            `|/  .'
        _______/  _ >--------------< _  \______.##._
              ((((_(                )_))))   .##. |
            / ```` `--------------' ''''\   |  | |
            (                             \  |  |-'
            )                             ) `--'
            (          _        _.---.__.-'
            `-.___.--' `------'

        ";
      Console.WriteLine(bakeryAscii);
      Console.WriteLine("Please [y] to place your order, [m] to view the menu and [n] to exit");
      string  continueAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
      if (continueAnswer == "y") {
          Console.WriteLine("How many loaves of bread would you like to purchase today?");
          int breadInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
            if (breadInput > 0 ) {
              Bread testBread = new Bread();
              int breadPrice = testBread.CalcBread(breadInput);
              Console.WriteLine("You have bought " + breadInput + " loaves of bread for: $" + breadPrice);
              Console.WriteLine("Would you like to buy some Pastry's today? [y] or [n]");
              string pastryAnswer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
              if (pastryAnswer == "y") {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of pastry's you would like to buy:");
                int pastryInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
                  if (pastryInput >= 0) {
                    Pastry testPastry = new Pastry();
                    int pastryPrice = testPastry.CalcPastry(pastryInput);
                    Console.WriteLine("You have bought " + pastryInput + " pastry's");
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your total bill is $" + breadPrice + pastryPrice);
                } 
                  else {            
                  negativeNumberError();    
                } 

                  } 
                  else if (pastryAnswer == "n") {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for Coming in, your total bill is $" + breadPrice);
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
                  }
  
            } else {   
              negativeNumberError();      
            }
      } else if (continueAnswer == "m") {
        Menu();
    } else if (continueAnswer == "n") {
      Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
    } else {
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
      Main();
    }
}

    public static void Menu() {
      Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        string menu = @"Fresh Bread: $5 each (loaf)
        Delicious Pastry: $2 each

        ** Special of the week **
        Bread: Buy 2, get 1 free!
        Pastry: 3 for $5!";
        Console.WriteLine(menu);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
        string menuAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
        Main();
    }
        public static void negativeNumberError() {
          Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
          Console.WriteLine("Error, please try again and enter a number greater than 0");
          Console.ReadLine();
          Main();
    }
    }
}
`````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321514/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: Use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0) to convert input to number, it will return false if received input is not an integer. For return `true`, you get the converted integer with `out` param.

Comment: I read all your code. I'm a picky and grumpy C# developer, but great job so far. Keep learning and keep going.

Comment: thank you Yong.  

Please check out my repo for the updated code.  
Next thing is.. seperating business and UI logic.  I feel like my main function is way too messy.. it was easy for me in javascript but I had a hard time with it here.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

`int breadInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`

you probably need something similar to

```
int breadInput;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many loaves of bread would you like to purchase today?");
}
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out breadInput));
```

I chose [do...while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do), instead of [while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while) (while is by far more common) because we need to ask the question before evaluating the response.

If I chose `while` then I would have to repeat the `WriteLine` line. Let's try with `while`:

```
Console.WriteLine("How many loaves of bread would you like to purchase today?");

int breadInput;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out breadInput));
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many loaves of bread would you like to purchase today?");
}
```

That's not beautiful, but the biggest problem is that one day I could change the question in one place and then forget to update the 2nd `WriteLine`.

#### < 1

Please note that the condition inside `while` can be expanded to deal with negative numbers. Anything that can go inside an `if` can go inside a `while`:

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out breadInput) || (breadInput <= 0));
```

## Helper methods

I would encourage you to create a helper method that you can reuse. This will keep you main logic looking clean. Here's an example:

```
// Concise code I can reuse for multiple questions
var ok = AskPositiveInt("How many loaves of bread would you like to purchase today?"
 , max: 100
 , out int breadInput);
if(!ok) 
{
   // todo  
}

(...)

static bool AskPositiveInt(string question, int max, out int number )
{
    // Here we can add as much validation as we wish
    Console.WriteLine(question);

    int numberOfTries = 5; //Number of tries before giving up
    for( int i = 0; i < numberOfTries; i++ )
    {
        
        var answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if(!int.TryParse(answer, out number))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide a number.");
            continue; // go back to 'for'
        } 

        if (number <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide a number.");
            continue; // go back to 'for'
        }

        if (number > max)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Insufficient stock. Please provide a number <{max}");
            continue; // go back to 'for'
        }

        //Everything OK
        return true;
    }
    
    number = 0;
    return false;
}
```

## Error handling

In your code you call `Main` in your `negativeNumberError` handler.

This won't work long term because you never leave the original `Main`.

If the number keeps being negative you are adding to the chain Main->Main->Main->Main. You have to come up with a better strategy.

Comment: Great answer! Clear and concise. An explanation of a `do` `while` loop may be helpful as they are not common in C# applications

Comment: WOW!!!! This website is amazing.  Thank you SO much.  

I learned about while in javascript but I havent seen them yet in c#.  My project deadline is this week and I managed to get everything working with error handling but I still have 2 big problems. 
1.  Using Auto-implemented properties is a requirement.  
2. Everything is in my main like you said.. I'm struggling to seperate User Logic from Business logic.. especially because I thought everything that had a read console goes in main.. 

THANK YOU

Comment: https://github.com/FaisalRana/CSharp.Bakery <-- here is a link to the updated REPO

Comment: Oh okay.  I understand about the error handling.  I will be sure to work on that in my next project.  

Im in 1 year coding program.. this is our second week in c# so I still have a lot to learn. 

Any idea how I can add auto implemented properties to this? first I gotta separate out the logic better and I think it will automatically be more apparent.