# System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format. how to fix

Tags: c#, sql

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNr41.png)

```
 private void btnGuncelle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sorgu = "UPDATE tablo_1 SET ad=@ad,soyad=@soyad,tc_kimlik=@tc_kimlik,dttarih=@dttarih,rahatsizlik=@rahatsizlik,mno=@mno WHERE mno=@no";
            komut = new SqlCommand(sorgu, baglanti);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", Convert.ToInt16(textBox6.Text));
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad", txtAdi.Text);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soyad", txtSoyadi.Text);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tc_kimlik", txtKimlik.Text);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rahatsizlik", txtRahatsizlik.Text);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dttarih", dateTimePicker1.Value);
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad2", textBox6.Text);
            baglanti.Open();
            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
            baglanti.Close();
            HastaGetir();
```

When i run the program everything works fine adding data and deleting data but when i uptade the data i having this error and the name changes to hasta_id how can i fix this?

Comment: Query text has `@mno` which is not added to Parameters collection

Comment: You can check other answers for this error - e. g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321514/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format
indicating that the textBox6.Text string cannot be parsed as Int16 value (so we would need to know what you enter in that text box causing the error)

Comment: nothing change when i write everything it will cause that problem again

Answer (score 0):

The information you provided is incomplete - the value of *textBox6.Text* is unknown at the time of the error
But probably it is not a 16bit integer, and therefore the *Convert.ToInt16()* had failed with *FormatException*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34990723)